# creating users in couchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Before I ask my question I would like to say thank you and also say sorry if this question is too simple or wrong for stack overflow but I really need some help.

**Question:**

I am using couchDB for the first time. I have created a registration form using ***HTML / AngularJS / Javascript*** now what I want to do is that a user can register and then login to view their personal information (i.e *name, email, password*)  nobody can see that information expect the person to whom the account belongs to.

How do I create this in couchDB. How do I create/register users in couchDB and what is purpose of the already in-built "_users" database within couchDB, is the "_users" database where I create my users?

Again I apologise if I have given some wrong information or if this is not the right way of asking the question here but I kinda need some help. So please try to answer.

If you can provide with some basic sample code that would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is purpose of the already in-built "_users" database within couchDB?

The _users database in couchdb is used to store the private information of users who will be managing different couchdb databases. Any user that you have in a _users database can be assigned as a member or an admin in the [_security](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html) document of the databases.

For every user you can ask for a [session](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#post--_session) from couchdb. couchdb will respond by sending you back a cookie. You can use that cookie in your own application.

For example this is the response that couchdb sends back when you authenticate:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 01:23:14 GMT
Server: CouchDB (Erlang/OTP)
Set-Cookie: AuthSession=cm9vdDo1MEJCRkYwMjq0LO0ylOIwShrgt8y-UkhI-c6BGw; Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Note the path in the set cookie header. `/` means that the cookie is "operative" in the root of couchdb url (which by default is `http://localhost:5984/`). So the cookie will work in

`http://localhost:5984/`, `http://localhost:5984/_something`,`http://localhost:5984/_something/_else` etc

But if your application is hosted in `http://localhost:3125/` then this cookie wont work. So you will need to use a middleware to extract this cookie and send it from your own application so that it is valid for your path  or host your application within couchdb.

So to answer your question

1. Store the user information in couchdb _users database.
2. Query the session endpoint to generate a cookie.
3. Reuse that cookie in your application by sending the set cookie header from your own application.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. Just have a few follow up questions.           I read that there are 2 types of authentication:                                                   1) Basic 2) cookie. Which one would do you think it the best way to go?        Also when I register a new user into my website/app do I save the user in the _users database? or do I save them in a JSON document in my different database? Again thank you.

Comment: No problem :) to answer your questions 1) basic authentication is only good when you are using a middleware 'cause the credentials are in the open. For your use case cookie authentication is more suitable. 2) Yes only way to generate cookies from couchdb is to  have the user in _users db. If you save them as a document in a different db you won't be able to use couchdb's built in cookie authentication. But you can store [custom fields](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html#users-documents) in the user documents.

Comment: Again thank you so much. you have made this easy to understand. Can I ask for just one more thing? I'm sorry for asking so many questions but I'm new to this and just need all the help I can get. If its possible can you give a very simple javascript example of adding users into _users db and creating a cookie authentication. I apologise if its too much to ask. Again thank you

Comment: Check out [couchjs](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-futon/blob/import-master/script/couch.js) file. Every operation of couchdb from client side. It includes functions for adding a document, requesting a session and deleting a session. Adding a user is no different from adding a simple document.  This should help you get started.